# Binding IIS site to alternate IP not accessible remotely - OK locally - Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, iis, windows-firewall

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server with multiple IPs (4 in total) associated with it. When I bind an IIS web site to one of the alternate ones I can browse too it locally but when I try to do it remotely, it times out....no messages in log etc. Does anyone know if there are Windows Firewall settings that need to be set for alternate IPs similar to the way you would do for a port?

Comment: Are all the IPs on the same subnet and bound to the same network adapter? Also check the `HTTP.SYS` logs in `%SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR`

Comment: Yes, they're all bound to the same adapter. There were no obvious clues in the log file that was in the directory referenced above. I can ping it though.

Comment: How about the subnet - are all the IPs on the same one?

Comment: You need to break down the problem. Is routing working, is name resolution working, is firewalling working, etc. first thing to try is to telnet from another machine to the IP which you think should work on port 80. Then do the same using the dns address. If you get a connection each time then its an IIS issue.

Comment: Telnet doesn't work but browsing to it locally on that server does....so it does not appear to be IIS issue. I opened up a ticket with service provider. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Enable windows firewall logging for drops and see your telnet test is blocked.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947815(v=ws.10).aspx