# IIS not working remotely with alternate IPs

Tags: iis, firewall, ip, windows-server-2016

(I see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/491654/binding-iis-site-to-alternate-ip-not-accessible-remotely-ok-locally-windows) being suggested - I have the same issue, but there were no accepted answers to that question)

We have a new dedicated server (`Windows Server 2016`) with our hosting provider. They've just allocated a few more IPs, which I've added to the network adapter with the correct subnet/gateway/etc values. However, there are issues accessing things remotely:

(I'm using the IIS 'Default Web Site' for now to eliminate [as the cause of the issue] any user permissions required by IIS for site paths).

When I bind the site to the primary IP of our server, I'm able to access it locally and remotely - it displays the IIS landing page as expected. However when I bind the site to any of the alternate IPs, I'm only able to access it locally from the server.

I noticed that I don't get ping responses from any of our new server's IPs, but I did with our old server's. AFAIK, the hosting provider has set up some external firewall for us. Perhaps they've just set it up to block ping requests.

This is possibly an issue with the provider but I'm wondering if there's something I could configure my side while I wait for their response.

Answer (score 2):

You talk about a managed firewall, thus;

I would not put all public IP on the server NIC card, but I would do rule within the firewall to redirect that traffic to your server, which in turn will know what to serve depending on the IP you bind each IIS site to.

So on the router its a inbound NAT rule for those public IP to your server private IP, and as the router know the state of the connection, it will answer with the correct public IP.

Thus for me it mean the one managing the firewall forgot something

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah - was an oversight on the hosting provider's side. They forgot to "allow the IPs through". Not gonna delete my question in case it helps someone else. Cheers..

Comment: @cpengin Glad it now work :) Dont forget to upvote or mark as aswered if it helped, or write your answer. As its a good question